# How to exclude master Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have created the following query which will get the data from all databases. when i execute the query i am getting error invalid column id. i have investigated and found the table tbl_table_A (example) is listed in master database and this table is not having column id. i have exlcluded this DB master but not sure why the query is still calling the master DB. kindly advise

Query :

```
CREATE TABLE ##tbl_data 

(
 [database_name] NVARCHAR(500), 
 id              INT, 
 last_run        DATETIME, 
 [next_run]      DATETIME, 
 last_run_status NVARCHAR(500) 

)



DECLARE @StartDate NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @EndDate NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @StartDate  = '10-Dec-2019 00:12:59'
SET @EndDate    = '10-Dec-2019 00:17:59'


SET @strSQL =

'
USE [?]

IF ''?'' <> ''master'' AND ''?'' <> ''model'' AND ''?'' <> ''msdb'' AND ''?'' <> ''tempdb''

BEGIN

IF OBJECT_ID(''tbl_table_A'') IS  NULL
RETURN;

insert into ##tbl_data 

SELECT ''?'', id,last_run,next_run,last_run_status

    FROM dbo.tbl_table_A nolock  

WHERE last_run  between cast ('''+@StartDate+''' as Datetime2) and cast ('''+@EndDate+''' as Datetime2)  


END'

EXEC dbo.sp_msforeachdb @strSQL

Select * from ##tbl_data
Drop table ##tbl_data
```

Answer (score 1):

> i have exlcluded this DB master but not sure why the query is still
>   calling the master DB

No, your code does not "call" `master`.
Here is your code where I use print instead of insert.
This way you can see what exactly db is checked and whether there is or there is not your table there:

```
declare @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @strSQL =

'
USE [?]

IF ''?'' <> ''master'' AND ''?'' <> ''model'' AND ''?'' <> ''msdb'' AND ''?'' <> ''tempdb''

BEGIN
print ''?''

IF OBJECT_ID(''tbl_table_A'') IS  NULL
begin
    print ''there is no table tbl_table_A''
    print ''----------------''
    RETURN;
end

    print ''***** THERE IS table tbl_table_A *****''
    print ''----------------''

END'

EXEC dbo.sp_msforeachdb @strSQL
```

Answer (score 0):

I always like to take a different approach to these types of problems. For one, I really dislike cursors and you don't really need one here. Also, sp_msforeachdb is not only undocumented it has some problems. It will sometimes skip databases and nobody really seems to know why. Aaron Bertrand discusses this and provides a better alternative here. https://sqlblog.org/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp_msforeachdb

I prefer to do something like below. There are no loops and won't run into weird behavior like skipping tables. It also does not require a global temp table which can have serious concurrency issues. This requires two dynamic sql statements. The first gets the list of databases with the table you want to find. Then we use that data to generate the dynamic sql statement against the list of database we want to search.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Databases') is not null
    drop table #Databases

DECLARE @StartDate NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @EndDate NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @StartDate  = '20191210 00:12:59'
    , @EndDate    = '20191210 00:17:59'
    , @strSQL = ''

declare @TableName sysname = 'tbl_table_A'

select @strSQL = @strSQL + 'select ''' + d.name + ''' from ' + quotename(d.name) + '.sys.tables where name = ''' + @TableName + ''' union all '
from sys.databases d

select @strSQL = left(@strSQL, len(@strSql) - 10) --this removes the last union all

CREATE TABLE #Databases 
(
    DatabaseName sysname
)

--select @strSQL

insert #Databases
(
    DatabaseName
)
exec sp_executesql @strSQL

set @strSQL = ''

select @strSQL = @strSQL + 'select ''' + d.DatabaseName + ''',  id, last_run, next_run, last_run_status from ' + quotename(d.DatabaseName) + '.dbo.' + @TableName + ' where last_run between @_StartDate and @_EndDate union all '
from #Databases d

select @strSQL = left(@strSQL, len(@strSql) - 10)

--select @strSQL

exec sp_executesql @strSQL, N'@_StartDate datetime, @_EndDate datetime', @_StartDate = @StartDate, @_EndDate = @EndDate
```